# SKProductsRequest Returning Empty Results

Tags: ios, xcode, ios5, in-app-purchase

I have looked over some of the other answers and they don't seem to help my situation. I have a new app that is nearly ready for its initial release and I am just working on the In App Purchase section. I have used IAP in a previous app so I thought the move over should be straight forward. The problem is, however, that whenever I run SKProductsRequest, it returns an empty results set.

I am using the following to make the request

```
productIdentifierList = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
[productIdentifierList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"xxxxxxxxxx"]];

SKProductsRequest *request = [[SKProductsRequest alloc] initWithProductIdentifiers:[NSSet setWithArray:productIdentifierList]];
```

And the response goes to

```
-(void)productsRequest:(SKProductsRequest *)request didReceiveResponse:(SKProductsResponse *)response {
    NSLog(@"Recieved Product Response %@",response.products);
    [productDetailsList addObjectsFromArray: response.products];
    [productDisplayTableView reloadData];
}
```

I just don't seem to be getting any results returned. I have checked the ids and they seem ok; I have also run from my iPhone device via Xcode and still had no luck. The response in the debugger doesn't give a lot away as well.

Can anyone suggest some fixes for this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that in new versions of IOS you no longer need to put in the full id of the app and then the iap id. Instead just put in the iap id.

```
[productIdentifierList addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"iap_id"]];
```

Comment: @ORStudios - Can you elaborate on this answer please? The product Identifier should match what is shown in iTunes Connect for the identifier. Typically like this com.companyname.appname.iapreference - I have the same issue, but not sure if it is related as the answer does not make sense to me. Thanks